# Store model name in an array rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, model

My requirement is something like this (but this doesn't work)

```
array=["Menu","Article","Comment"]
array.each do |x|
   x.find 1     # the x is of class String
   p x.id
end
```

each elements of the array is an model name in my application. The 'x' obtained inside the looping is of class string but i want it to be of a model.

I want to do certain same task on each of the models, doing something like this can reduce some 60 lines of code in my program. can anybody help..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `constantize` like so:

```
array=["Menu","Article","Comment"]
array.each do |x|
  klass = x.constantize
  klass.find 1
  p klass.id
end
```

http://apidock.com/rails/String/constantize

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
array=["Menu","Article","Comment"]
array.each do |x|
    a = (Object.const_get x).find 1
    p a.id
end
```

Answer (score 1):

In ActiveSupport (part of Rails) there is a method [`constantize`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html#method-i-constantize) available on `String`s which might help you:

```
array=["Menu","Article","Comment"]
array.each do |x|
  instance = x.constantize.find 1
  p instance.id
end
```